# gwtbootstrap3-extras slider does not work properly on IPhone6s (OS.10.2.1)

Tags: gwt, gwt-bootstrap, gwtbootstrap3

I tried to use the [Slider](https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#slider) in my project.

When I tried to drag it using Chrome developer environment with device emulation turned on the tool-tips showing the current value are visible, but I cannot drag it.

When I tried the very same project on my IPhone, I can drag it perfectly but the tool-tips don't show up, so I can't see the value.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Someone edited my original text and changed tooltips to tool-tips which is actually wrong because the correct spelling for the tooltips class is exactly written like that

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using the attribute  does the trick and it actually works on touch devices like my IPhone 6s  . This is remarable because tooltips don't work on buttons using gwtbootstrap3. Actually they work but they take the first tip to show up. So you need to tip twice on a button which is not good.